# Using Bladejs with Meteor

Tags: meteor, laravel-blade, node-blade

I recently added the node-blade smart package to my meteor and have static content displaying fine. However, I'm not able to use any template variables. Before I installed blade, the template variables worked fine with handlebars. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

### console output

```
ReferenceError: player is not defined
    at ~/meteor/project/views/info.blade:1:1

1 > .player-name.large= player.name
2 | .alliance-name= alliance.name
3 | .world-name= world.name
4 | 

    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/compiler.js:138:23))
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/runtime.js:323:5
    at runtime.loadTemplate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/runtime.js:272:6)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/blade.js:45:4
    at Compiler.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/compiler.js:185:2)
    at compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/blade.js:41:12)
    at Object.compileFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/blade.js:66:3)
    at Object.runtime.loadTemplate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/runtime.js:269:23)
    at Object.runtime.include (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/runtime.js:320:22)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/blade/lib/compiler.js:138:23))
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

### info.blade

```
.player-name.large= player.name
```

### client.js

```
if(Meteor.is_client) {
    Template.info.player = function(){
        var data = Session.get( 'data' );
        return data.player;
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you using a body.blade template?  If so, does your body.blade file include your info.blade file?

Comment: well it includes a template that in turn includes this template

Comment: Same issue. And just including one template.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Helpers are now permitted in body templates.

You cannot use helpers or certain global variables in head <del>or body</del> templates.  You can't even use them in templates that are included by head <del>or body</del> templates.

Checkout these links for more information:

- <del>https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/issues/98</del>
- https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/wiki/Using-Blade-with-Meteor

Comment: @VanCoding - It is now, I think.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** This answer is no longer accurate as of Blade 3.0.0 stable.  `body.blade` templates may not contain dynamic stuff like helpers, references to `Session`, etc.

---

In ['Using Blade with Meteor'](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/wiki/Using-Blade-with-Meteor) says that

> References to Session are not allowed in head or body templates. This is by design, and it is not a bug. In Handlebars, you could use Session or Meteor within a  tag, but not a  tag. I didn't like the Handlebars implementation, so you're stuck with this one. The body.blade template is mostly for static content (i.e. a loading page or whatever). Once your application is loaded, you can do `$("body").replaceWith(Meteor.ui.render(Template.homepage) )`; from your application code.

So, this is saying that, on initialization, one could not have dynamic generated templates.

To workaround this, documentation suggests

```
$("body").replaceWith(Meteor.ui.render(Template.homepage) )
```

I replaced `replaceWith` method with `html` method. See an example that's working for me:

```
# ./the_cow.coffee
if Meteor.isClient
  $ ->
    $('body').html Meteor.render -> Template.test
      user:
        name: 'Pill'

# ./views/test.blade
#test Testing
p= user.name
```

See the compiled JavaScript:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  $(function() {
    return $('body').html(Meteor.render(function() {
      return Template.test({
        user: {
          name: 'Pill'
        }
      });
    }));
  });
}
```

Don't know if there is a shorter way to write it.