# Meteor+Blade template variables catch 22

Tags: meteor, node-blade

I'm trying to use a variable in my Blade template, but I always get

> ReferenceError: files is not defined

My understanding is that the proper way to pass a variable to a template is something like this (`client/ceres.js`):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Files = new Meteor.Collection('files');
    Template['files'].files = function() {
        return Files.find();
    }
});
```

(Copying from the "todos" example)

And then I should be able to use it in my template, `views/files.blade`:

```
ul
    foreach files as file
        li= file.filename
```

But I guess the variable is passed to the template too late? But if I take my JS out of `Meteor.js` then `Template` isn't defined.

So I don't get it. Either my template doesn't exist, or the variable doesn't exist, and it always crashes. How do I pass a simple variable along?

---

Same error with this:

```
ul
    - for(var i=0; i<files.length; ++i)
        li= files[i].filename
```

Comment: if you tried `foreach Files.find() as file` does it help?

Comment: @Akshat: No, it doesn't. The `.find()` should already have been applied via my client JS, but regardless, the `files` variable itself doesn't exist, so adding a property to it isn't going to help. Nevertheless, I tried it, and the error indeed comes back the same: "ReferenceError: files is not defined"

Comment: I mean because Files with the capital is the reference to the collection, I know using Template.files.files = function().. works with handlebars, but it might be different for blade if you can just run js in the blade template

Comment: @Akshat: Oops! I didn't see the capital F. It doesn't recognize `Files` either.

Comment: It looks like its a more common issue, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207015/using-bladejs-with-meteor

Comment: @Akshat: Oh... I was under the impression that they would work in `included` files with how the docs were worded... I hope this little kink is worked out because replacing the contents with JS seems like a bit of a hack to me.

Comment: `Meteor.ui` was removed in 0.4.0 https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-talk/SAdKvESyN7o

Comment: Try using `Meteor.render` it should also do the job, of note the input argument must be in a functional form function() {return .. } (I'm not sure what it was before with ui.render so it could work as a swap replacement too

Comment: @Akshat: Sort of works. I can't iterate over this collection like they've suggested.

Comment: Nevermind. That was my bad... I had `Template.files.files = Files.find()` but making it a function that returns that somehow changes things...works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't *include* files that use Template variables either. i.e., you can't use the `include` directive in Blade <del>at all</del> if you want to use variables in your template that haven't been initialized by Meteor yet -- you have to insert your template via jQuery/JS after the DOM has loaded. Example:

**views/body.blade:**

```
.container
    h1 Page Title
    #content
```

**views/files.blade:**

```
ul
    foreach files as file
        - console.log(file);
        li= file.filename
```

**client/main.js:**

```
Files = new Meteor.Collection('files');
Template.files.files = function() {
    return Files.find();
};

$(function() {
    $('#content').html(Meteor.render(Template.files));
});
```

Comment: This should no longer be the case.  `include` should now work fine in Blade 3.0.3.

Comment: You may want to modify/remove the answer above, as it does not relate to the question at hand.  In addition, I am pretty sure that `include`s now work just fine after some recent bugfixes.  If not, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Hrm? How doesn't it relate? The issue was that I couldn't use variables in a Blade template; this is a workaround. In your answer you say that it will only work if the files are included in the proper order (which is presently controlled by filenames), that's not really a "fix" either, is it?

Comment: Ah, I think that I understand now. The answer confused me because of the words "i.e., you can't use the include directive in Blade at all"

Comment: @BMiner: Oh..I should change the verbiage on that. Without variables though, the `include` directive isn't very useful :-) Not that it's your fault, we just have to wait until the Meteor guys figure out the best way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Meteor that is actively being worked on.

The problem is that Meteor prevents smart packages from specifying the load order of files.  [See issue here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/181).

Because of this issue, it is possible that your client-side JavaScript will run before the templates are loaded.  (There is a hack in Meteor that ensures Handlebars templates load before your custom code)  For example, `Template.foo.helperName = function() { ... }` will fail if `Template.foo` has not yet been defined.

Check the generated HTML (view source) for the initial page load to see if your client-side JavaScript code is loading before the template is defined.  If so, you may get an Error like:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'helperName' of undefined`
```

To workaround this issue, try putting your client-side code in a folder with a different name.  I believe that Meteor currently sorts files alphabetically when determining the load order.  See the troubleshooting section on [this page](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/wiki/Using-Blade-with-Meteor#troubleshooting-and-known-issues) for more information.

A similar workaround is to utilize `Meteor.startup` when adding view helpers to your views.  That is, you can wrap your `Template.foo.helperName = ...` stuff in a `Meteor.startup` call.  If you are using a `body.blade` template, though, you can end up with the opposite problem (i.e. the "catch 22") in which your `body.blade` template starts rendering before view helpers get setup.  In this case, you can get errors since those helpers/variables are not yet defined.  The solution here is to avoid using `body.blade` templates and only render the initial template once all view helpers have been loaded (i.e. at the end of your `Meteor.startup` routine).

At any rate, all of these workarounds are rather lame.  :(  But, alas!  These issues should be fixed soon.

As soon as Meteor fixes the issue described above, I will modify the Blade smart package to enforce the load order of compiled templates.  My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I'm glad it's being worked on. Thank you for your help (and Blade itself!). Until the include-ordering is resolved in Meteor, however, I don't consider this a proper solution. I shouldn't have to name my files alphabetically.

Comment: @Mark - Agreed - renaming files is a lame workaround.  I've been pushing the Meteor team, but they are a very busy group. :)

Comment: Another workaround would be to utilize `Meteor.startup` when adding view helpers to your views.  That is, you can wrap your `Template.foo.helperName = ...` stuff in a `Meteor.startup` call.